# Wordpress. Почему плагин store locator не определяет месторасположение пользователя на мобильных устройствах?

Tags: wordpress, google-maps-api

Добрый день!
Плагины типа store locator определяют расположения пользователя во всех браузерах кроме Оперы и браузеров на мобильных устройствах. Почему на моб. устройствах не работает функция определения месторасположения. Перепробывал несколько плагинов - результат один и тот же. сайт: https://fashion-style-tm.ua/

Answer (score 0):

Вот [пример сайта](https://cplclub.kagg.eu/) с работающим плагином Geo My WP.

Надо принимать во внимание следующие вещи:
1) должны быть подключены API геолокации (судя по информации из консоли, у Вас они подключены)
2) некоторые плагины требуют размещения на сайте библиотек GeoIP.dat и GeoIPv6.dat